# Array of objects value with some weight age value not comes in proper sequence

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object like this:

```
let messageScoreData = {
  messagescore: [
    {
      userid: "5bacc8c6563a882a1ca7756a",
      score: 2605.4
    },
    {
      userid: "5bacc98431481e0520856df8",
      score: 1013.2
    },
    {
      userid: "5bc6d0bb26f1bb1b44a790c6",
      score: 41
    },
    {
      userid: "5bc6d0bb26f1bb1b44a790c9",
      score: 29
    }
  ],
  messagescorebefore: [
    {
      userid: "5bacc8c6563a882a1ca7756a",
      score: 3754
    },
    {
      userid: "5bacc98431481e0520856df8",
      score: 1259.8
    },
    {
      userid: "5bc6d0bb26f1bb1b44a790c6",
      score: 98
    },
    {
      userid: "5bced078d62b321d08f012af",
      score: 22
    },
    {
      userid: "5bcec1ad11302529f452b31e",
      score: 6
    },
    {
      userid: "5c10afec8c587d2fac8c356e",
      score: 6
    },
    {
      userid: "5c07b7f199848528e86e9359",
      score: 3
    },
    {
      userid: "5bed1373f94b611de4425259",
      score: 2
    },
    {
      userid: "5c21ccff833a5006fc5a98af",
      score: 2
    },
    {
      userid: "5c21ccff82e32c05c4043410",
      score: 1
    }
  ]
};
```

Now we will provide the weight-age value i.e messagescorebefore array have 0.4 value and messagescore have 0.6 value;
For that I have the algorithm which sequentialize the value with weight-age value. i.e

```
var result = messageScoreData;

var columns = [
  {
    name: "messagescorebefore",
    value: 0.4
  },
  {
    name: "messagescore",
    value: 0.6
  }
];

var total = {};

for (let column of columns) {
  for (let userid of result[column.name]) {
    var alphabet = userid.userid;
    if (total[alphabet]) {
      total[alphabet] += column.value;
    } else {
      total[alphabet] = column.value;
    }
  }
}
const valueholder = Object.keys(total)
  .map(key => ({ name: key, value: total[key] }))
  .sort((f, s) => s.value - f.value);
console.log(valueholder);
```

By this Algo output is :

```
[ { name: '5bacc8c6563a882a1ca7756a', value: 1 },
  { name: '5bc6d0bb26f1bb1b44a790c6', value: 1 },
  { name: '5bacc98431481e0520856df8', value: 1 },
  { name: '5bc6d0bb26f1bb1b44a790c9', value: 0.6 },
  { name: '5bcec1ad11302529f452b31e', value: 0.4 },
  { name: '5bced078d62b321d08f012af', value: 0.4 },
  { name: '5c07b7f199848528e86e9359', value: 0.4 },
  { name: '5bed1373f94b611de4425259', value: 0.4 },
  { name: '5c21ccff833a5006fc5a98af', value: 0.4 },
  { name: '5c21ccff82e32c05c4043410', value: 0.4 },
  { name: '5c10afec8c587d2fac8c356e', value: 0.4 } ]
```

Problem is userid: "5bacc98431481e0520856df8" will come on second position on both array but after final calculation this will come under 3rd position which is wrong.
expected output will be like this:

```
[     { name: '5bacc8c6563a882a1ca7756a', value: 1 },
      { name: '5bacc98431481e0520856df8', value: 1 },
      { name: '5bc6d0bb26f1bb1b44a790c6', value: 1 },
      { name: '5bc6d0bb26f1bb1b44a790c9', value: 0.6 },
      { name: '5bced078d62b321d08f012af', value: 0.4 },
      { name: '5bcec1ad11302529f452b31e', value: 0.4 },
      { name: '5c10afec8c587d2fac8c356e', value: 0.4 },
      { name: '5c07b7f199848528e86e9359', value: 0.4 },
      { name: '5bed1373f94b611de4425259', value: 0.4 },
      { name: '5c21ccff833a5006fc5a98af', value: 0.4 },
]
```

Any help is really appreciated for this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you want to preserve relative order of elements. normal sort function is not guaranteed to preserve relative order. so we need some tricks to keep relative order like below.

```js
let messageScoreData = {
    messagescore: [
        {
            userid: "5bacc8c6563a882a1ca7756a",
            score: 2605.4
        },
        {
            userid: "5bacc98431481e0520856df8",
            score: 1013.2
        },
        {
            userid: "5bc6d0bb26f1bb1b44a790c6",
            score: 41
        },
        {
            userid: "5bc6d0bb26f1bb1b44a790c9",
            score: 29
        }
    ],
    messagescorebefore: [
        {
            userid: "5bacc8c6563a882a1ca7756a",
            score: 3754
        },
        {
            userid: "5bacc98431481e0520856df8",
            score: 1259.8
        },
        {
            userid: "5bc6d0bb26f1bb1b44a790c6",
            score: 98
        },
        {
            userid: "5bced078d62b321d08f012af",
            score: 22
        },
        {
            userid: "5bcec1ad11302529f452b31e",
            score: 6
        },
        {
            userid: "5c10afec8c587d2fac8c356e",
            score: 6
        },
        {
            userid: "5c07b7f199848528e86e9359",
            score: 3
        },
        {
            userid: "5bed1373f94b611de4425259",
            score: 2
        },
        {
            userid: "5c21ccff833a5006fc5a98af",
            score: 2
        },
        {
            userid: "5c21ccff82e32c05c4043410",
            score: 1
        }
    ]
};

var result = messageScoreData;

var columns = [
    {
        name: "messagescorebefore",
        value: 0.4
    },
    {
        name: "messagescore",
        value: 0.6
    }
];

var total = [];

for (let column of columns) {
    for (let userid of result[column.name]) {
        var alphabet = userid.userid;
        if (total[alphabet]) {
            total[alphabet] += column.value;
        } else {
            total[alphabet] = column.value;
        }
    }
}

let res = Object.keys(total).map((k, idx) => {
    return {
        name: k,
        value: total[k],
        index: idx
    }
})
var output = res.sort((f, s) => {
    if (s.value < f.value) return -1;
    if (s.value > f.value) return 1;
    return f.index - s.index
})
console.log("output : ", output)
```

Comment: You could simplify this solution to: `var output = res.sort((f, s) => s.value - f.value || f.index - s.index)`.

Comment: @Kevin yes we can do it.

Answer (score 1):

The observed behaviour is expected since you are sorting the *values* in a descending way: `.sort((f, s) => s.value - f.value);`. From your example it seems that you want to sort the entries lexicographically on the names. In that case you should sort according to the names:

```
const valueholder = Object.keys(total)
  .map(key => ({ name: key, value: total[key] }))
  .sort((f, s) => f.name.localeCompare(s.name));
```

If you want to sort them primarily on the values (descending) and secondarily on the names (ascending) then do:

```
const valueholder = Object.keys(total)
      .map(key => ({ name: key, value: total[key] }))
      .sort((f, s) => s.value - f.value || f.name.localeCompare(s.name));
```

In this case, if two entries have the same value the difference `s.value - f.value` will be 0. Since this is a falsy value, `f.name.localeCompare(s.name)` will be evaluated, effectively sorting the values lexicographically on their name.

If you want to sort the entries based on their values but retain the original order for entries with the same value you can do the following:

```
const entries = Object.keys(total)
      .map(key => ({ name: key, value: total[key] }))
const valueholder = entries.sort((f, s) => s.value - f.value || arr.indexOf(f) - arr.indexOf(s));
```

The reason we need to explicitly sort on their original order is because the built-in sorting algorithm is not (guaranteed to be) stable. Note that the above sorting is not very efficient since we use `indexOf`. I leave it as an exercise to first loop through the array and accumulate all indexes in a map that maps names to indexes. As such, when sorting you can look up the indexes rather than computing them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for *stable sort*, i.e. preserving the original order of elements of the array with equal value, you have to add a comparison of the indexes of the key array (assuming that this has the proper ordering):

```
const keys = Object.keys(total);
const valueholder = keys
  .map(key => ({ name: key, value: total[key] }))
  .sort((f, s) => s.value - f.value || keys.indexOf(f.name) < keys.indexOf(s.name));
```